# What's is the most efficient way to generate a random image on the iPhone

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

For testing purposes I would like to generate a large quantity of unique images and store them in the Camera Roll (via ALAssetsLibrary) on an iPhone. Ideally these should approximate the size of real user photos.

I've tried considering generating images with random colors, but these tend to compress to smaller sized files than typical camera pictures.

I'm currently generating an image from entirely random bits but I was wondering if there were any other ways I should consider which would better approximate pictures taken by real people.

My aim is to do generate rapidly as possible so pulling images from flickr is going to be too IO bound.

Comment: Get a dozen or two images, slice them up into squares, then recombine randomly.  Or you could simply use horizontal slices.

Comment: The reason they "compressed" to a smaller size is because the image you create is one color. An image of one color only needs a few bytes of storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a few images and simply have a method that draws a sequential number (or time) on them and saves them as an image. So each is unique but allows testing typical images. Numbering also allows you to test to make sure the correct image is being loaded as desired.

Comment: Simple yet effective!